Does partial flow separation due to toggle input affect the physics of paraglider/ canopy controls?
A skydiving canopy designer said the following:

Airflow is separated even before stall on a big portion of the canopy.... It's specific to [the] way toggle[s] distort the trailing edge.

Is this true, and if so, how would this fit into our understanding of how paraglider controls work or the equivalent for (the much less efficient) skydiving canopies?
My thoughts:

If this were true, wouldn't we see a lot of fabric deformation on parts of the wing in deep brakes? Yet the images below look smooth.

Would flow separation reduce lift without affecting drag? This might help explain why toggle inputs are much more "draggy" than ailerons.

Is this why toggles increase the chance of front collapse? (I'll make a separate question for this)

I'm guessing that this is less significant in modern paragliders, which seem to have less distortion with toggle input.




